# RxSwift: How to add simple observer to int value

Tags: swift, rx-swift, observers

I want to use rxswift to observe hash value of my model.

I have something like registration form and I need to show "save change" only if some data was changed.

I'm not using any binding.

I'll just want to observe hash of data.

Comment: You can try with BehaviorRelay and its observable as well.

Comment: @Leena can you show an example?

Answer (score 0):

Code with explanation:-

```
//Variable where you can store value as well as you can keep watch on change
 let aVar:BehaviorRelay<Int> = BehaviorRelay(value : 0)
 let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

  //Observe changes 
  aVar.asObservable().subscribe(onNext: {_ in
    //Do whatever you need to do here 
    }, onError: nil, onCompleted: nil, onDisposed: nil).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```